# When they say $\text{Hom}(A,B) \approx \text{Hom}(C,D)$ in category theory, what do they mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

For instance in Weibel.  Do they mean that the two hom sets are bijective or something in addition to that?

> Show that $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A, \prod_i C_i) \approx \prod_i \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A, C_i)$ and ...

No more info about general category $\mathcal{C}$ is given.

Comment: Usually just as sets (assuming they are sets), though if there is some more structure to the Hom's, then probably isomorphic as such. Alternatively, it might mean as bifunctors.

Comment: It depends on what $A, B, C, D$ are. Can you give an example?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan example given

Comment: In that example they definitely mean as sets (again, assuming the category is locally small).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft and by that you mean just show bijectivity?

Comment: In the example you can also 1) find a function and its inverse or 2) show that the set on the left satisfies the universality property of products.

Comment: Yes, being isomorphic as sets means that there is a bijection between them.

Comment: In the example Weibel means *at least* that there is a bijection between the sets, but in fact there is a *natural* bijection between them (as a functor of the $A$ and of the $C_i$); this is why I asked.

Comment: The same convention arises for adjunctions, namely that we sometimes informally check for a bijection of hom-sets, when we should really be checking for a natural bijection.  In fact, this example is exactly an adjunction: the product over an indexing set $I$ is right adjoint to the diagonal functor $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}^I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a correspondence of sets. Assume the categories are locally small.

First note that if $f:B\to A$, then there is the induced arrow

$f^{*}:\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A, \prod_i C_i)\to \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(B, \prod_i C_i)$ defined by $\phi \mapsto \phi \circ f.$

We also have the arrow

$\theta_f:\prod_i \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A, C_i)\to \prod_i \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(B, C_i)$ defined by $(g_i)_{i\in I}\mapsto (g_i\circ f)_{i\in I}$

Then, $\approx $ means two things:

1). the correspondence is bijective: this is clear if we just note that by the UMP of the product,

$\left (\phi: A\to \prod  C_i \right )\leftrightarrow (\pi_i\circ \phi )_{i\in I},\ $is a bijection, where $\pi_i$ are the canonical projections from the product.

Call this bijection $()^{\star }$.

2). $()^{\star }$ is $\textit { natural in A }:\ $

if $f:B\to A$ then $(\phi \circ f)^{\star }=\theta_f((\phi )^{\star })$.

The following calculation shows that this is true:

compute the LHS:

$(\phi \circ f)^{\star }=(\pi_i\circ \phi\circ f)_{i\in I}$

and the RHS:

$\theta_f((\phi )^{\star })=\theta_f(\pi_i\circ \phi)_{i\in I}=(\pi_i\circ \phi \circ f)_{i\in I}$